# Adding profit from a file

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, addition

I am trying to add the profit value sold from a list of bikes on a text file, the program reads two text files and calculates the amount of profit made based on the quantity of bikes wanted by the customer, and the current inventory, my code is as following,

`int temp = 0;`

```
    for( int i =0; i < B.length; i++){
        temp = B[i].getInventory();
        if (B[i].getModel().equalsIgnoreCase(clientRequest[i][1]) && (B[i].getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(clientRequest[i][2]))){
            B[i].setInventory(B[i].getInventory() - Integer.parseInt(clientRequest[i][3]));
            if (B[i].getInventory() < 0){
                earnings = earnings + (B[i].getSold() * temp);
                clientRequest[i][3] = String.valueOf(B[i].getInventory());
```

The rest of the code works fine, it's just that the earnings return 0.0

Comment: The code contains a lot of conditions not explained. It would be easier to maintain the code with more descriptive variable names. And your earnings is increased only if the inventory is below 0.

Comment: `B[i].getInventory()  < 0`  To my best guess, don't you think inventory should be greater than or equal to zero? Put some logging statements in between to see what your code is trying to calculate. Also using i,j,B or any other variable that doesn't make sense is the worst form of naming convention.